# How can I execute an alias from a shell defined in .screenrc?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have some aliases setup in ~/.bash_aliases that I want to execute in .screenrc

```
chdir ~/projects/profullstack/edcast/edc-web
screen -t SHELL 0 edc-web-local      
chdir ~/projects/profullstack/edcast/edc-cms
screen -t SHELL 1 edc-cms-local
chdir ~/projects/profullstack/edcast/edcast
screen -t SHELL 2 edcast-local
screen -t mysql 3 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/mysql@5.6/bin/mysql.server start
screen -t elastic 4 /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/elasticsearch@2.4/bin/elasticsearch
```

These aliases are not found though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `edc-web-local` is an example alias. The only way I got it to work was adding `bash -ic` in front of the command:

```bsh
screen -t SHELL 0 bash -ic edc-web-local
```

.. and the same trick for the other alias commands

`-c` tells that the next argument (that is not an option) is a command to exectue. `-i` tells that the shell is run in "interactive" mode which means it turns on alias resolution and loads `~/.bashrc` (which typically loads `~/.bash_aliases`).

Comment: edc-web-local is hte alias that is in .bash_aliases.

Comment: Did my proposal work?

Comment: yes it did. what does the -c do?

Comment: Improved answer..

Comment: Beautiful. Exactly what I was looking for.